# django ForeignKey NOT NULL constraint

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

estoy intentando crear un relacion de modelos en django pero me tope con este error.

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: app_server.client_id
```

si alguien pudiera ayudarme a comprender el error o a solucionarlo se lo agradeceria mucho.

## models.py

```
class Report_detail(models.Model):
    server_id = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key_detail = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    value_detail = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    detail_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

class Client(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    #report_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.client}'

class Server(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    servername = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

## views.py

```
#client = get_object_or_404(Client, id=request.POST['client'])
client = Client.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['client']).first()
dbserver_id, created = Db_server.objects.get_or_create(
            client= client,
            servername=servername,
            ip=ip)
```

saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que el error te esta diciendo es que no puedes crear un objeto Db_server con el campo client como vacio, ya que no acepta valores nulos.

Lo mas probable es que este pasando por esta linea:

```
client = Client.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['client']).first()
```

Si no existe un cliente con el pk que obtienes de request.POST['client'], el método first() de devolverá como valor un None.

Entonces en la siguiente linea:

```
dbserver_id, created = Db_server.objects.get_or_create(
            client= client,
            servername=servername,
            ip=ip)
```

Intentara obtener o crear un objeto Db_server con client como None, el campo client del modelo Server no permite valores nulos, entonces al momento de intentar crearlo fallara, una posible solución es que primero cheques que el Cliente exista antes de intentar obtener o crear el objeto Db_server, algo así:

```
client = Client.objects.filter(pk=request.POST['client']).first()
if client:
    dbserver_id, created = Db_server.objects.get_or_create(
                client= client,
                servername=servername,
                ip=ip)
```

la otra opcion es que dejes tu instruccion anterior con get_object_or_404() asi en caso de no existir el cliente no deje pasar a la siguiente instrucción.